# Change <div> content from file depending on string from URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

so I have 3 files namely 'test1.php', 'test2.php', 'test3.php'. And in the 'index.php' I have this code:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#test1">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test3">test3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="main_content">
    <?php
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if (strpos($url, 'test1') !== false) {
            include 'test1.php';
        }
        if (strpos($url, 'test2') !== false) {
            include 'test2.php';
        }
        if (strpos($url, 'test3') !== false) {
            include 'test3.php';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

and on the test#.php just has a simple `<h1>Test #</h1>` in it just so I could see if the contents are changing but it doesn't work.

So what I was hoping is that whenever I click a link from the navigation, the URL of course changes to: localhost/index.php#test1; but the content doesn't change? Any ideas on how to properly do this? Either JavaScript or PHP, THANKSSSSS

Comment: Can you use `localhost/index.php?test=1`? And then simply `$_GET['test'] ?: '1'`?

Answer (score 0):

you got `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` wrong

> > you can use GET parameter

**OR to use  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

you have to use String functions**

URLs formatted like this  > `https://IndiaOneWay.com/index.php` OR On Local server `http://localhost/folderName/1/index.php`

```
$myURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']



$myURL  // >> http://localhost/folderName/*test2.php (trim URL part using str_replace function, replace with nothing "")

$lenthofURL = strlen($myURL);
```

Get Lenth of Url strlen() [40Charecters] >> find position of "-" stripos("/")[rd position] >> Chop strings left part and store it in variable do same with remaining